# Change case of all column names with Ibis

Tags: python, ibis

I have an [Ibis](http://ibis-project.org/) table named `t`. Its column names are all lowercase. I want to change them all to uppercase. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `relabel` method of Ibis table objects renames columns. It can be used to make all the column names uppercase like this:

```py
t = t.relabel(dict(zip(t.columns, [x.upper() for x in t.columns])))
```